# Creating and filtering a list of predefined funcs

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a list of Func's in a class called ValidationMethods. I use these in a Validator class by passing them into Validator.Validate(Func). I was wondering if there is a way to wrap each func so that I can overload Validate to take an IEnumerable and specify a where class to filter based on some enum value.

I am doing this in an effort to make the API more closely follow the open / close principle where the Validator can take in more validation types as the need arises without modification of the validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. You want an enum to filter the funcs:

```
enum Category {
  F1,
  F2
}
```

Then a wrapper for each func:

```
class FWrap<TIn, TOut> //depending on your arities
{
  public Func<TIn, TOut> Fnc {get; set;} 
  public Category Cat {get; set;}

  //some constructor and stuff
}
```

After that, there shouldn't be any problem:

```
IEnumerable<FWrap<t1,t2>> funcs = getFuncs();
validators = funcs.Where(f => f.Cat == Category.F1)
```

and so on... I hpe thats what you expected.

Comment: That's a good way, but what about a simple IDictionary<Category, Func<TIn, TOut>> ?

Comment: I didn't think about indexing a dict with an enum. That's even more elegant, of course. Although, like this, it could be filtered with more than one criteria.

Comment: Doh! That is pretty much what was staring me in the face. Cheers both!